# Dropdown list 'disabled' parameter does not work

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, button, drop-down-menu

I am currently working with javascript/React and I have some problems with the last one.
In my window, I have several buttons, and below, a dropdown list. The idea is to disable this dropdown list. It is only enabled once you click a button, based on the *disabled* parameter. Among the button parameters, there is also a onClick() which does something else (but at the beginning of this function, I implemented some code so that the value in *disabled* would change). Which is why I want to use the *disabled* parameter to enable/disable the dropdown list. 
So this is supposed to be easy...

Here is a part of the html :

```
<DropdownButton
        title={"Type : "}
        className="sequence-dropdown"
        disabled={true}
        key="sequence-dropdown"
        id="sequence-dropdown"
        >
        <MenuItem onClick={() => this.changeValue(value1)}>Value 1</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={() => this.changeValue(value2)}>Value 2</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={() => this.changeValue(value3)}>Value 3</MenuItem>

      </DropdownButton>
```

And here is the code supposed to enable the dropdown list, contained in the function changeValue().

```
var statusDropdown = document.getElementById('sequence-dropdown').disabled;
if (statusDropdown === true) {
  console.log(document.getElementById('sequence-dropdown').disabled)
  document.getElementById('sequence-dropdown').disabled = false;
  console.log(document.getElementById('sequence-dropdown').disabled)
}
else if (statusDropdown === false) {
  //console.log(statusDropdownMapType)
  document.getElementById('sequence-dropdown').disabled = true;
  //console.log(statusDropdownMapType)
}
```

I did not try it, but I think I could simply use :

```
document.getElementById('sequence-dropdown').disabled = !document.getElementById('sequence-dropdown').disabled
```

But that's not the issue here.

My problem is : the button is well disabled at the beginning (with some grey color indicator). When I click a button, the grey color disappears, the component style is normal, and the *disabled* parameter is well changed.

BUT when I click on the dropdown, the list does not appear... It is like I was just clicking a button, nothing happens...

Does anyone know why ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

`document.getElementById('sequence-dropdown').setAttribute("disabled","disabled");`
and
`document.getElementById('sequence-dropdown').removeAttribute("disabled");`

regards Halliballi

Comment: From wht I understand, setAttribute() is used to get the actual value of a parameter and removeAttribute() to delete it. But does setAttribute change the value ? I tried to use it instead of "document.getElementById('sequence-dropdown').disabled = false;", but the disabled value does not even change this time.

Comment: When I use "document.getElementById('sequence-dropdown').disabled = false;", the value changes as I want, but the list is blocked

Answer (score 0):

If you set `disabled={true}` everytime the component renders it will be disabled. I would use another approach, like this:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {disabled: true};
}

...

render () {
   const {disabled} = this.state;
   return (
       <DropdownButton
        title={"Type : "}
        className="sequence-dropdown"
        disabled={disabled}
        key="sequence-dropdown"
        id="sequence-dropdown">
           <MenuItem onClick={() => this.changeValue(value1)}>Value 1</MenuItem>
           <MenuItem onClick={() => this.changeValue(value2)}>Value 2</MenuItem>
           <MenuItem onClick={() => this.changeValue(value3)}>Value 3</MenuItem>
        </DropdownButton>
   );
}
```

Then, since I can see you only change the state from disabled to enabled and viceversa, when you click your button this would be the approach:

```
this.setState((oldState) => {
   return {disabled: !oldState.disabled};
});
```

This way is more React. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use disabled={dropdownOpen}. I declared dropdownOpen as true in the constructor's state. But now it does not even change the parameter's value ! I don't know if this has anything to do with the problem, but I have other variables declared in the constructor's state. Can I still use "this.react.setState((oldState) => {return {dropdownOpen: !oldState.dropdownOpen}})" in a function just like that, as you said ? No need to precise other variables ?

Comment: you only specify what you need to change, and trust me, it works and doesn't affect the other variables. Also, I don't understand what you mean with `But now it does not even change the parameter's value`

Comment: I used console.log() to check dropdownOpen value. Do you mean to write this code in a new file ? Or can I stay in my current class ? When you use setState(), do you need to specify the value for every state variable ?

Comment: No, you don't need to use other file, the `this.setState(() => ...);` will be in your button action in order to enable or disable your dropdown. You DO NOT need to specify the value for every state variable, only for those variables you need to change. The state is an object... and you are changing only the attributes you need to change, the rest remain with their values.

Comment: `this.setState((oldState)=>{return {disabled: !oldState.disabled};});` will set a new state for `disabled` that will be the opposite for the previous `oldState.disabled` value, notice the `!` symbol.